# SQL Date Formats - Counting days since date field

Tags: sql, data-manipulation, presto, date-formatting

I am working with some dates in SQL and wanted wanted help to manipulate it. I have a list of birthdates and wanted to do things such as...

1. Cast the date in a select statement (e.g. if a person is born before 2000 is 'pre-2000' and those born after 2000 are 'post-2000'.
2. Filter the selections so only those born after 2000 are included in the statement.
3. Calculate the number of days in current time since the person's date of birth.
4. Reformat the date with letters inbetween e.g. "1990y 11m 01d"

The format of the field is DATE.

How can I do so?

Sample date is "1990-11-01". I am using Amazon Athena to query the data.

Comment: What is your exact database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?  We need to know this.  Also, please _delete_ the external image link, and instead include the sample data directly in your question, as _text_.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I have now added your points into my question.

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working for you?